# Por que al agregar una imagen en CSS no sale?

Tags: css, html5

Estoy trabajando en un formulario para agarrar experiencia en HTML y CSS

Sin embargo, al querer importar una imagen en CSS no me sale.

Codigo **CSS y HTML**:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');


.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
  

}

h1{
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Robot', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  
  <h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form by </h1>
  <p id="description"> This is an exercise that I made to learn more about the basics of HTML5 and CSS</p>
  <form id="survey-form">
    
  <!---Name--->
    <label for="name" id="name-label">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
    placeholder="Antonio Sein" required>

<!---Email--->
    <label for="email" id="email-label">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
    placeholder="test@test" required>

<!---Number--->
    <label for="number" id="number-label">Number: </label>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="number" min="1" max="8" placeholder="618-133-01-34">

<!---Dropdown--->
    <label for="dropdown">Why are you looking this code?</label>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option> I was just looking </option>
      <option> I want to hire you </option>
      <option> Want to give you some feedback</option>
    </select>

<!---Checkbox--->
    <label for="checkbox">What do you think about this survey?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="option1">
    <label for="option1"> It is good <label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option2" value="option2">
    <label for="option1"> It could be better <label><br>

<!---Radio--->
  <label for="checkbox">Are you interested to get in contact?</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" value="radio1">
  <label for="html">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio1" value="radio2">
  <label for="radio2">No</label><br>

  <!---textarea--->
    <label for="textarea"> Leave any review in order to improve my knowledge: </label>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" >
    </textarea>



    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Cabe mencionar, que si en el CSS cambio el **.bg-image a body**, si me sale el background image.

Lo unico que quiero hacer es que quiero agregar el background image separado del body para asi poder aprender a usar los filtros de CSS y asi poder saber un poco mas de diseño web.

Alguna recomendacion o sugerencia la verdad estaria muy agradecido.

Disculpen por la duda tan tonta, sin embargo, por mas que busque no estoy encontrando la solucion.

Answer (score 1):

te falta definir los atributos `width` y `height`
puedes hacerlo desde el contenedor padre y darle `width: 100%`
o definirlos para el elemento mismo

```
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.thumbnail {
  background-image: url("./photo.png");
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
}

.background {
  background-image: url("./photo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver dicho problema.

Tuve que usar el body en el css y despues para cambiar el background image usar

```
body::before
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar en la respuesta cómo quedó el código? Además, no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.